# multiple v-model in components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

is there any way to make this code simplier?

```
<b-address 
    v-model:name="address.name" 
    v-model:addressLine="address.addressLine"
    v-model:streetNumber="address.streetNumber" 
    v-model:town="address.town" 
    v-model:country="address.country"
    v-model:postcode="address.postcode" 
    v-model:phoneNumber="address.phoneNumber"
    v-model:homeAddress="address.homeAddress" 
/>
```

it would be nice if some shorthand would exist, some like this:

```
<b-address 
    v-model="address" 
/>
```

then, since b-address is a component and address is an object, shorthand would be great!
any ideas? Thank you

Comment: This shortand doesn't exists AFAIK. But you can pass the address object as a v-model and in your `b-address` component, bind the fields to `address.name` directly. But you won't be able to pass any other prop than an address like object.

Answer (score 0):

in case the component is not made by you or you do not have the possibility to go and modify that code, nom you cannot :(

if instead, that component is yours, then a hypothesis could be to do
**v-model:fullAddress** giving access to the whole object as a model!

with a result like this

```html
<b-address v-model:fullAddress="address" />
```